# PHP Stopping a person pressing Submit multiple times

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have the below form, and after the form the PHP requests a Curl which can take a while. Because of this they keep pressing the submit button thinking that nothing has happened. This causes multiple entries in the database. Could someone help me and let me know what to put in to stop this.

I tried the Javascript solution in the first answer but it stopped the PHP script that followed. Not what I wanted. Sorry

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css2/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
        <!--webfonts-->
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text.css'/>
        <!--//webfonts-->

        <center><img class="displayed" src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:128px;height:128px;"></center>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contactform" >
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
            <h1><span>Sign Up</span> <lable> The Brook on Sneydes</lable> </h1>
            <div class="inset">
                <p>
            <center><label ><?php echo $text; ?></label></center>

                        <label for="first">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first" id="first" value="" placeholder="" required/>
                </p>
                <p>
                        <label for="last">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last" id="last" value="" placeholder="" required/>
                </p>

        <p>
          <label for="mobile">Mobile Number</label>
          <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="" placeholder="" required/>
      </p>
        <p>
          <label for="email">Email Address</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="" required/>
        </p>


       </div>

              <p class="p-container">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">


              </p>
        </form>
    </div>
            <!-----start-copyright---->
                    <div class="copy-right">
                        <p> &copy; 2016 <a href="http://spearheaddigital.com.au/">Spearhead Digital</a>. All rights reserved.</p>
                    </div>
                <!-----//end-copyright---->
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST) ){

$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// Other Code

}
```

Comment: This is js part not php's

Comment: 1. Use JavaScript, after they press the button SHOW THEM, that something is happening.

2. You could also save the information that a given user is running this function right now in the cookie in PHP, so that you can check against it if they run this form again.

Comment: Just disable the button on first click itself... Then it wont submit again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the submit button when submitting the form.

An example using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#contactform').submit(function() {
            $('input[type=submit]', this).prop("disabled", true);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Awesome. Where is the best place to place the code? After the isset line?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You have to put this code in your HTML's head section. Please make sure that you've included the jQuery framework before.

Comment: You're an absolute legend. Thank you.

Comment: I have done this and I have found an issue. Once I press submit, the curl and redirect after the submission dont happen? Any thoughts?